# building linux kernel module with a yasm assembly file

Tags: assembly, linux-device-driver

I am trying to build a linux driver and I want to incorporate in it a .asm file which should be built using yasm.
How should I specify that in the Makefile?
Currently it says "No rule to make target" since this is an asm file and not S file.
If I change its suffix to .S it tries to build it using the default assembler and it fails because they have a different syntax.
What should I do to make it work?

Comment: Add a rule that uses yasm to build it?

Comment: I added a rule:
x.o: x.asm
 yasm -f elf64 $< -o $@
but it didn't help: make[6]: *** No rule to make target `x.o', needed by `y.o'

Answer (score 0):

Object files which are not build with KBuild system should have name

```
<x>.o_shipped
```

In Kbuild rules such files should be referred to without `_shipped` suffix:

```
<y>-m := <x>.o
```

See [Documentation/kbuild.modules.txt](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/Documentation/kbuild/modules.txt) (section "Binary Blobs") for more info.